# search an array and do a specific task based on if a value is found

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, hash

Ok let me ask this another way.  This is an example of an inciident table I'm going to import in a csv format.

```
    id:
    incident_datetime: 2012-09-24 08:07:00.000000+0000
    location: Hamburg
    report_nr: 33-11-00201
    responsible_party: John
    area_resident: No
    street: 6108 FoxHunt
    city: Lexington
    state: Ky
    home_phone: 111-111-1111
    cell_phone: 222-222-2222
    insurance_carrier_name: Nationwide
    insurance_carrier_street: Waller
    insurance_carrier_city: Lexington
    insurance_carrier_state: KY
    insurance_carrier_phone: 666-666-6666
    insurance_carrier_contact: Jason
    policy_nr: 2sdf2sdf
    vin_nr: ZTZHK3fhr5546107407
    license_nr: 520-VDH
    vehicle_make: Toyota
    vehicle_model: Tacoma
    vehicle_year: 2004
    created_at: 
    updated_at:
    status: Recieved
    user_id: 16
    resp_zip: 40509
    insur_zip: 40509
```

And here is the code for the rakefile.

```
    require 'csv'

    namespace :import_incidents_csv do

        task :create_incidents => :environment do
            puts "Import Incidents"

            csv_text = File.read('c:/rails/thumb/costrecovery_csv/lib/csv_import/incidents.csv')
            csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
            @incident_id_array = []
            csv.each do |row|
                row = row.to_hash.with_indifferent_access
                Incident.create!(row.to_hash.symbolize_keys)
                @incident_id_array << Incident.last.id
            end

       end
    end
```

The id at the top will automatically get assigned a value when it gets dumped into the database.  I'm then taking that id value and saving it in an array and creating a timesheet for it.  This is what the timesheet looks like.

```
    id:
    name:
    date:
    incident_id: x
    created_at:
    updated_at:
```

The timesheet needs to be created because a bunch of models "belong to it".  And here is the rakefile to create this:

```
    require 'csv'

    namespace :import_timesheets_csv do

        task :create_timesheets => :environment do
            puts "Import Timesheets"

            csv_text = File.read('c:/rails/thumb/costrecovery_csv/lib/csv_import/timesheets.csv')
            csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
            @timesheet_id_array = []
            csv.each_with_index do |row,index|
                row = row.to_hash.with_indifferent_access
                Timesheet.create!(row.to_hash.symbolize_keys)
                @timesheet_id_array << Timesheet.last.id
                timesheet = Timesheet.last
                timesheet.incident_id = @incident_id_array[index]
                timesheet.save
            end

        end
    end
```

So at this point, I've created a new incident, and it's linked to a new timesheet I just created.  Now I want to import a csv file creating safety_officers.  Here is what the file would look like.

```
    id: 
    name: Safety Officer 1
    first_hour: 1
    additional_hours: 2
    total_hours: 3
    hazmat_hours: 0.5
    rate1:
    rate2:
    timesheet_id:
    created_at:
    updated_at:
```

And here is the code for the Importing the safety_officer.csv file.

```
    require 'csv'

    namespace :import_safety_officers_csv do

        task :create_safety_officers => :environment do
            puts "Import Safety Officers"

            csv_text = File.read('c:/rails/thumb/costrecovery_csv/lib/csv_import/safety_officers.csv')
            csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
            csv.each_with_index do |row,index|
                row = row.to_hash.with_indifferent_access
                SafetyOfficer.create!(row.to_hash.symbolize_keys)
                safety_officer = SafetyOfficer.last
                safety_officer.timesheet_id = @timesheet_id_array[index]
                safety_officer.save
            end
        end
    end
```

So above is an example of 1 incident report being imported, 1 timesheet being imported/created and 1 safety officer being imported.  I'm trying to figure out how my code needs to be modified so the safety officers know which incident report they belong to.  How do I assign them the proper timesheet_id that corresponds to their incident.  I have several other models that I have to do this with as well but i just need to get it figured out for one of them and then I can duplicate it for the rest.  And all of these are saved as different rake files and are executed by one master rake task which looks like this.

```
    require 'csv'

    namespace :combine_csv do

        task :combine => :environment do
            Rake::Task["import_incidents_csv:create_incidents"].invoke
                                                                                                                  Rake::Task["import_timesheets_csv:create_timesheets"].invoke              
            Rake::Task["import_safety_officers_csv:create_safety_officers"].invoke
        end
    end
```

Comment: Use better naming to avoid confusion. How does the timesheet get linked with the saftey_report?  Maybe show one record of each file.

Comment: Well, I'm confused. The title doesn't seem to have anything to do with the actual question. Despite the tags, it appears you would best be helped by some ActiveRecord basics.

Comment: When you say "their incident", how do you know which incident belongs to a Safety Officer?

Comment: i will add a column to the safty_officer table via a migration.  The column will have the same report_nr that is found on the incident report.  The files that will be sent to me will be pre-populated with this info.